# Put links in images that are located in <script>

Tags: javascript, html

I'm new to html, and I also have no idea how to work with js, so can I insert a link in multiple images inside of javascript of an html?

Here is a code that make the image change every time I refresh,

What I need to do is make these image clickable, and leading to another site

Preferably, I'd want to try to make it so that the js can lead to a code in html, so i can also add stuff such as height

```
  <a href="3.html"> <img src="3w.png" alt="car" height="333"> </a>
```

```js
function random_imglink() {
  var myimages = new Array()
  myimages[1] = "1.png"
  myimages[2] = "2.png"
  myimages[3] = "3w.png"
  myimages[4] = "4w.png"

  var ry = Math.floor(Math.random() * myimages.length)

  if (ry == 0)
    ry = 1
  document.write('<img src="' + myimages[ry] + '" border=0>')
}

random_imglink()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Arrays are 0 based so no need to force 1 when 0
2. Just change the HTML to be a link
3. It is recommended to not use document.write, so instead insert it into a container

I am using [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) to create the link and eventListener to see when the page has loaded

```js
const myimages = ["1.png", "2.png", "3w.png",  "4w.png"]
const links = ["page1.html","page2.html","page3.html","page4.html"];

function random_imglink() {
  var ry = Math.floor(Math.random() * myimages.length)
  return `<a href="${links[ry]}"><img src="${myimages[ry]}" height="333" border=0/></a>`;
}

window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() { 
  document.getElementById("linkContainer").innerHTML = random_imglink();
});
```

```html
<div id="linkContainer"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you a lot, but i might be doing something wrong, but i cant get it to display anything, and for some reason the <script> ends at the ` after the </a>

Comment: nevermind i saw my error, thank you!